# Why does these sudo commands fail?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to add a crontab entry from a script as a normal user, so I use `sudo` to get `root` permissions, but fails no matter what I try.

```
$ sudo { crontab -u root -l; echo ' 15  9  *  *  * root /opt/script.sh'; } | crontab -u root
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

$ sudo echo ' 15  9  *  *  * root /opt/script.sh' >> /etc/crontab
bash: /etc/crontab: Permission denied
$ sudo echo ok
ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sudo echo ' 15  9  *  *  * root /opt/script.sh' >> /etc/crontab`, `sudo echo ' 15  9  *  *  * root /opt/script.sh'` is ran first then the shell takes the output of the `sudo` command and appends it to `/etc/crontab`. Since the shell is started as a normal user and so doesn't have root privileges, the shell can't write to `/etc/crontab`, which only `root` can modify. To solve the problem one starts a subshell as root, which allows it to append to `/etc/crontab`. Fortunately, this has already been implemented as `su -c`, however since the system uses `sudo`, `sudo` has to be prepended. The fixed command is `sudo sh -c "echo ' 15  9  *  *  * root /opt/script.sh' >> /etc/crontab"`

Comment: I thought the question was "Why does these sudo commands fail?" , while this answer is to the question "How can i put a line in crontab with sudo?" or "how can i run a shell command in sudo"

Comment: @kappa `"echo ' 15 9 * * * root /opt/script.sh' >> /etc/crontab` can be replaced with any other shell command.

Comment: sudo sh -c can be replaced by sudo -s.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are running

```
sudo echo .......
```

as "su" then writing the result to /etc/crontab with:

```
>> /etc/crontab
```

so in the moment you are writing to /etc/crontab you're not "su" anymore

Comment: How would you go around this?

Comment: "sudo crontab -e"  is the preferred way to do it

Comment: @hek2mgl the command after pipe is still not executed as su

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Or invoke an new shell `sudo bash -c "echo \"hello\" >> file"`

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't understand the example. I haven't used `tee` before. Can you give a full example?

Comment: @kappa Thanks, I frequently forget this... :) (at) Sandra have no better example, it was just wrong.. sorry